# Dynamically create splits in dataframe using numpy.split?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am currently segmenting a dataframe using numpy.split. My question is if I can rewrite my code to dynamically take in user input from a function to determine number of segments and segment percentages.

My current code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df_1, df_2, df_3 = np.split(df, [int(0.5*len(df)), int(0.75*len(df))])
```

This code works well to create three dataframes with first 50% of rows in the first dataframe and 25% in each of the other two dataframes.

Can I write a function so that I create the segments dynamically based on the user inputting how many segments they need and the percentages associated with each segment?

Thanks!

Comment: Add `np.split` does is take 'row'` slices, `[df[0:n1], df[n1:n2], df[n2:n3,...]`.  Create your own slice steps and apply them.  There's no deep magic.

Comment: @hpaulj I can create my own steps, but I'm trying to dynamically create them based on user input. I.E. code should work whether user inputs split into 3 even sections or 5 even sections.

Comment: Then 'dynamically' calculate the your own steps.  But I don't quite understand what you mean by 'dynamically'.  Are you focusing on that `df1,df2,df3=` unpacking?  Unpacking like that is 'static' (though newer Python allows for `*rest` terms.  But `split` produces a list.  Do you really need to unpack that list?